# How to set marked for backup on volume

Tags: backup, windows-home-server, bitlocker

I want to use Bitlocker with Windows Home Server but I have read that I need to make sure the volume is marked for backup.  I am unclear on how I do this?  I have searched around on my volume and do not see anything about marking for backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that means is that all bitlocker encrypted volumes on the Windows Home Server CLIENTS must be marked for backup within the Windows Home Server backup options for those clients.